# Connect disjoint edges in binary image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I performed some operations on an image of a cube and I obtained a binary image of the edges of the cube which are disconnected at some places.The image I obtained is shown below:

[image]

I want to join the sides to make it a closed figure.I have tried the following:

```
BW = im2bw(image,0.5);                   
BW = imdilate(BW,strel('square',5));   
figure,imshow(BW);
```

But this only thickens the image.It does not connect the edges.I have also tried bwmorph() and various other functions, but it is not working.Can anyone please suggest any function or steps to connect the edges? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Read in the input image
img = im2bw(imread('http://i.imgur.com/Bl7zhcn.jpg'));

%// There seems to be white border, which seems to be non-intended and
%// therefore could be removed
img = img(5:end-4,5:end-4);

%// Thin input binary image, find the endpoints in it and connect them
im1 = bwmorph(img,'thin',Inf);
[x,y] = find(bwmorph(im1,'endpoints'));
for iter = 1:numel(x)-1
    two_pts = [y(iter) x(iter) y(iter+1) x(iter+1)];
    shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape', 'Lines', 'BorderColor', 'White');
    rectangle = int32(two_pts);
    im1 = step(shapeInserter, im1, rectangle);
end
figure,imshow(im1),title('Thinned endpoints connected image')

%// Dilate the output image a bit
se = strel('diamond', 1);
im2 = imdilate(im1,se);
figure,imshow(im2),title('Dilated Thinned endpoints connected image')

%// Get a convex shaped blob from the endpoints connected and dilate image
im3 = bwconvhull(im2,'objects',4);
figure,imshow(im3),title('Convex blob corresponding to previous output')

%// Detect the boundary of the convex shaped blob and 
%// "attach" to the input image to get the final output
im4 = bwboundaries(im3);
idx = im4{:};

im5 = false(size(im3));
im5(sub2ind(size(im5),idx(:,1),idx(:,2))) = 1;

img_out = img;
img_out(im5==1 & img==0)=1;
figure,imshow(img_out),title('Final output')
```

Debug images -

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Matt Well this code should work for convex shaped single blob in an image and with modifications could be extended to multiple blobs in a single image(I would think). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes thank you.I will work on the code :) I have another question that is related to this.It is actually the step that comes before connecting edges.Can I ask it here?

Comment: The image that I have posted in my question was obtained after I performed the Sobel operation on it and converting it to binary.The image had a shadow under it, so I performed thresholding before converting it to a binary image.But this threshold varies with each image.Is there any way for setting a constant threshold that works in the general case?

Comment: I will post the code that I have written for my new question below

Comment: @Matt Hmm, it sounds like it would suit better as a separate question. If you decide to go that way, show/attach the input image and what `sobel` resulted in. Good luck!

Comment: @Matt If this solution did help you, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it!. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me a lot.I have been struggling to connect these borders for the past week, 24x7! Thank you :)

Comment: @Matt Wow, that's a long time! Well, good luck with the new post!

Answer (score 2):

I used the above code to write the following one.I haven't tested it on many images and it may not be as efficient as the one above but it executes faster comparatively.So I thought I would post it as a solution.

```
I = imread('image.jpg');  % your original image
I=im2bw(I);
figure,imshow(I)
I= I(5:end-4,5:end-4);
im1 = bwmorph(I,'thin',Inf);
[x,y] = find(bwmorph(im1,'endpoints'));
for iter = 1:numel(x)-1
im1=linept(im1, x(iter), y(iter), x(iter+1), y(iter+1));
end
im2=imfill(im1,'holes');
figure,imshow(im2);
BW = edge(im2);
figure,imshow(BW);
se = strel('diamond', 1);
im3 = imdilate(BW,se);
figure,imshow(im3);
```

The final result is this:
[image: cube]

I got the "linept" function from here:http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4177-connect-two-pixels

Comment: Very kool! Good job really.